# Debugging .net Core IModelBinder has Visual Studio Skipping Lines

Tags: c#, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, xunit

I'm attempting to debug my xUnit(s) relating to a custom IModelBinder implementation and the Visual Studio debugger is :

1. Not hitting all my breakpoints in JsonModelBinder
2. Not exiting on Task.Completed even though it hits each Task.Completed.

None of my other xUnits behave this way. At this point the only Units giving me troubles are one associated with the asp.net core pipeline.  I tried cleaning my solution and re-adding project refs thinking a may have had an old pdb file?

I'm using Moq, xUnit, VS2017, ASP.net Core 2.2.

// JsonModelBinder

```
public class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> _jsonOptions;
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public JsonModelBinder() { }

    public JsonModelBinder(IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> jsonOptions, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _jsonOptions = jsonOptions;
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindCtx)
    {
        string modelName = bindCtx.ModelName;

        ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult = bindCtx.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindCtx.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindCtx.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

        string value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        JToken token;

        try
        {
            token = JToken.Parse(value);
        }
        catch (JsonReaderException)
        {
            bindCtx.ModelState.TryAddModelError(modelName,  "Invalid json object.");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bindCtx.ModelState.TryAddModelError(modelName, ex.Message);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        bindCtx.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(token);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

// xUnits

```
public class JsonModelBinderFacts
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task BindModelAsync_WithNullValueProvider_SetsDefaultError()
    {
        // arrange

        var bindingCtx = new Mock<ModelBindingContext>();
        bindingCtx
            .Setup(x => x.ModelName)
            .Returns("Test");

        var valueProvider = new Mock<IValueProvider>();

        bindingCtx
            .Setup(x => x.ValueProvider)
            .Returns(valueProvider.Object);

        var providerResult = new ValueProviderResult(new StringValues(new []{ "test"}));

        valueProvider
            .Setup(x => x.GetValue("Test"))
            .Returns(providerResult);

        var binder = new JsonModelBinder();

        // act

        await binder.BindModelAsync(bindingCtx.Object)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        // assert

        Assert.True(bindingCtx.Object.ModelState.ErrorCount > 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered on this post : [Asp.net core 2.2 ModelBinder Unit Test Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032498/asp-net-core-2-2-modelbinder-unit-test-issues)

Something is getting corrupted in the hidden .vs folder in the root of the solution.  Deleting the contents of this folder and rebuilding the solution worked.

Comment: Glad you got a solution to your problem. If the provided answer worked as you stated, then you should accept it as the answer. Since this question directly relates to the linked question, I closed this question as a duplicate of the issues experienced in the other question. You can always delete this question if you wish. Provided the other answer to this question gets no up votes. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch on all exceptions (Ctrl+Alt+E) and check Common Language Runtime Exceptions, I get FileNotFound exceptions running your tests.

Add reference to missing packages (I found these 2)

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />`
`<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />`

Should solve it.

HTH

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the resolution.